# Why does Facebook using videos and png as gif?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We can post an animated GIF on facebook.But Facebook saves it as a video. for an example [This is an animated GIF on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/AnonymousPortugalInternacional/posts/738780352888437) . But if you look at the source, then you can find [This video](https://video-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xpt1/v/t42.4659-2/12619699_962527057155385_383034426_n.mp4?oh=b1c345e225d11773ca57de9d782ccee1&oe=56C5ED9A) . Also, all animated stickers are [like this](https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t39.1997-6/s600x600/10574699_313423715485115_1798761909_n.png) on the source. They are animated by a JS. Why Facebook doesn't use GIF files directly? Is there any good reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not easily start/stop GIF animations.

“Stopping” them would only be possible by replacing them with a static image anyway; and trying to get a GIF animation started with precise timing is hard to achieve cross-browser as well – some browsers play an animation only once, if that same image gets used somewhere else again later, they won’t re-play the animation, start it at different times, etc.

So most likely this choice was made to have full control in that regard, which using a video instead of a GIF easily offers.

(Plus, advanced current video codecs often offer better compression than the rather old GIF format.)